# Excel::Writer::XLSX writing unformatted date

Tags: excel, perl

I have a script which is using the `Spreadsheet::XLSX` module to read in data which includes unformatted dates.  When I open the spreadsheet on the desktop it does show the dates in the `mm/dd/yyyy` format.  After I am finished reading them I write them out to a spreadsheet using the `Excel::Writer::XLSX` module. I am basically adding the next date in sequence. Everything works fine until I then read in from the spreadsheet that I created.  It ONLY reads the date as formatted, no matter if I use either of these to read them:

```
$cell->{Val}
$cell->value()
```

This is the write format I'm using to write out the date.  Just so I'm clear, I am writing out the date in the unformatted value using this format.  If I don't use the `num_format` then the dates are in the `ddddd` format when I open the spreadsheet.

```
$workbook->add_format(bold => 1, align => 'center', num_format => 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

How do I get it to be consistent when reading the spreadsheets and also viewing the dates as `mm/dd/yyyy` when I open it?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [CELL FORMATTING](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#CELL-FORMATTING) section:

> Cell formatting is defined through a Format object. Format objects are created by calling the workbook `add_format()` method as follows:
>
> ```
> my $format2 = $workbook->add_format( %props );    # Set at creation
> ```
>
> The format object holds all the formatting properties that can be applied to a cell, a row or a column. **The process of setting these properties is discussed in the next section.**

Another quote from [write_date_time()](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#write_date_time(-$row,-$col,-$date_string,-$format-)) section:

> A date should always have a `$format`, otherwise it will appear as a number, see "DATES AND TIME IN EXCEL" and "CELL FORMATTING".

According to this your code should be:

```perl
my $date_format = $workbook->add_format(
    bold       => 1,
    align      => 'center',
    num_format => 'mm/dd/yyyy'
);

# apply format to a specific cell
# $string should be in ISO-8601 format as UTC, e.g. yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ
$worksheet->write_date_time($row, $column, $string, $date_format);
```

My weapon of choice for wrangling time stamps would be the [Date::Manip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Manip::Examples) distribution.